# Transpose time stamp data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have another set of data where there are multiple timestamp.

```
Name    Timestamp               Status
------------------------------------------
Ahmed   02/11/2016 1:03:37 PM   Check In
Ahmed   02/11/2016 3:42:21 PM   Check In
Ahmed   02/11/2016 7:00:49 PM   Check In
Ahmed   02/11/2016 7:00:55 PM   Check In
Ahmed   03/11/2016 12:01:03 AM  Check Out
Ahmed   03/11/2016 11:50:32 PM  Check In
Ahmed   04/11/2016 11:45:00 AM  Check Out
```

I am trying to get the output as below

```
Name    Check in date   check out date  check in time   check out time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ahmed   02/11/2016      03/11/2016       1:03:37 PM     12:01:03 AM
Ahmed   03/11/2016      04/11/2016      11:50:32 AM     11:45:00 PM
```

Kindly help

Comment: What attempt did you make to solve this problem before posting, and what error did you get?    I recommend that you google `SQL gaps and islands problem`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(10), checkin, 101) check_in_date,
convert(varchar(10), checkin, 101) check_out_date,
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), checkin, 22), 11)) check_in_time,
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), checkin, 22), 11)) check_out_time
from (
select name, 
min(case when status = 'Check In' then timestamp end) checkin,
max(case when status = 'Check Out' then timestamp end) checkOut
from table
group by name, convert(varchar(10), timestamp, 101)) t;
```

Comment: It's a good idea to have ELSE branches in all your case statements.

Comment: This will only produce one row per `name`.

Comment: Dear Gurwinder... I tried this for the condition I have given in the example and it is giving one output with the first date as check in and last date as check out. however I found some of the timestamp with missing on checkin or check out status.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Name
      ,CheckInDate  = format(min(TimeStamp),'dd/MM/yyyy')
      ,CheckOutDate = format(CheckOut,'dd/MM/yyyy')
      ,CheckInTime  = format(min(TimeStamp),'hh:mm:ss tt')
      ,CheckOutTime = format(CheckOut,'hh:mm:ss tt')
 From (
        Select *
              ,CheckOut=(Select min(TimeStamp) From @YourTable where Status='Check Out' and TimeStamp>=A.TimeStamp and Name=A.Name)
         From @YourTable A
      ) A
 Group By Name,CheckOut
```

Returns

```
Name    CheckInDate   CheckOutDate      CheckInTime    CheckOutTime
Ahmed   02/11/2016    03/11/2016        01:03:37 PM    12:01:03 AM
Ahmed   03/11/2016    04/11/2016        11:50:32 PM    11:45:00 AM
```

Comment: Dear John.... Thank you for the above solution. It is working for the conditions I have given in example, however for some of the timestamp there is no check in or check out status. could you please help on this

Comment: @Michael Perhaps you could edit your question with a better sample set and how you would want to handle/display these exceptions